# sched.c file remains unchanged after kernel compilation

Tags: unix, process, kernel, fork, scheduling

I have a problem regarding with unix kernel compilation . We are designing a scheduling algorithm for processses. We have changed the contents of fork.c ,sched.c . However , while fork.c is being updated after kernel compilation , sched.c remains unchanged . I have searched about this kind of problem over the web but I couldn't find a solution . I will be very happy if any of you have an idea in this subject .

Thank you !

Comment: sched.o: sched.c   # maybe a typo in the question ?

Comment: i don't take any errors about typing ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you use `make` for building your kernel:

`make` may skip making of a target if timestamps of dependencies are older than the existing target file.

If you edit some source file, and `make` does not recompile it to a new object file,
You should check clocks of your hosts and make clean for removing files that may have future timestamps.

In you case, You expect that `sched.c` is changed during compilation of the kernel, right?. This is *quite* uncommon, because usually sources are untouched and object files are changed. Maybe that causes some strange circular depedency that prevents the wanted action:

```
sched.c : sched.c
        command_to_edit -i sched.c -o sched.c
```

Maybe `make` does not build `sched.c`, because timestamp of target (`sched.c`) is same as timestamp of dependencies (`sched.c`).

Comment: thank you for your answer , we overcame this problem but we have a new problem right now , when we start our new scheduling algorithm the computer is freezing ? does it take so long time to pass another scheduling algorithm ?